# Should I use foreign keys in this example?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have an (example) database consisting of three tables: `user, car, key`. The `user` can have multiple `cars`, and each `car` can have multiple `keys`. As of now, the `car` and `key` tables have a foreign key associating themselves with the `user` and `car` (below) - and this works fine.

[image: Database Schema Image]

My issue is, if a car were to no longer exist and be deleted, this wouldn't necessarily mean that the key no longer exists. However once the car has been deleted, there is no way to associate the key to the user - as the car being referenced by the key's foreign key is now gone.

I realise I could store the user ID alongside each key, but I assumed this beat the point of having foreign keys and wasn't the best way of doing it.

So, what's the most acceptable way around this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that you retain the record in the car but you have a column that says it is no longer active (deleted or no longer in circulation or something). If you have foreign key association with other tables, the database architecture would be like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the key is still there and has some meaning (as you don't want to delete the key), 
I would "soft delete" the car, eg. add a bit column "deleted" to the table *car*.

Comment: Better to add a deleted date column, null means and not deleted, otherwise the date of deletion (a handy thing to know sometimes)

Comment: True, but that could be also in a separate audit log, which IMO is even better.

Comment: "You can create more tables to hold the data you don't want to hold in this table" - hmm